# Why do custom membership provider files have to be in the app_code folder of my web app?

Tags: .net, asp.net, provider, app-code

I'm writing a custom memberhsip provider based on the source for the SQL provider and I tried first making the SQL Provider a separate project. Yet, the web app wouldn't recognize it unless I put all the source in an APP_Code folder in my web app.

Is this how you implement a custom provider? I thought I could simply reference the provider project from the web app and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you specify the type as "Namespace.Type, Assembly.Name" if you have your provider in a compiled assembly. Like "System.String, mscorlib" or "System.Web.UI.Design.ControlDesigner, System.Design".

Example:

```
<membership defaultProvider="OlaMembershipProvider">  
  <providers>  
    <add name="OlaMembershipProvider" type="OpenAccess.Web.OlaMembershipProvider, OpenAccess.ClientSide" />  
  </providers>
</membership>
```